# Как отключить флаг -Werror, который стоит по умолчанию

Tags: c++, cmake

Проблем в общем такая. Когда в коде возникает какой-либо warning, cmake отказывается его компилировать. К примеру, если в коде не использованные переменные, компилятор выводит:

```
error: unused parameter ‘frame’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
```

Если Warning другого типа, то в место `unused-parameter` соответственно другие слова. Например, если сравнивать `int` и `long unsigned int` то выводит ошибку:

```
error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Werror=sign-compare]
```

В CMakeLists.txt никаких флагов не стоит вообще. Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать этот флаг?

Comment: Не очень понятно, но попробуйте #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Что именно не понятно? Попробовал define, не помогло

Comment: А можете показать `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: А разве werror дефолтный? CMakeCache.txt в студию

Comment: @ARHovsepyan про _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS - это Win32? что то подсказывает мне у ТС gcc или шланг

Comment: Все разобрался, дело было в библиотеки, которую я подключал через `add_subdirectory`. Там был CMakeLists.txt в котором был прописан этот флаг....

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос в заголовке - поможет флаг `-Wno-error`